# Subquery returned more than 1 value. by using 2 subquery's and subtracting them

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to subtract 2 subquery's and then get the answer from that to show in my select statement

I did not find any tuturials or other forum posts that could help my problem

```
DECLARE @Year int
set @Year = 2018
SET @Verloop = 12
SELECT Lijst.positie as [Positie], titel as [Titel], Lijst.top2000jaar as [Jaar]
, Artiest.naam as [Artiest], Verloop = (SELECT positie
FROM Lijst
WHERE top2000jaar LIKE @Year)-(SELECT positie
FROM Lijst
WHERE top2000jaar LIKE @Year -1)
FROM Song
INNER JOIN Lijst ON Song.songid = Lijst.songid
INNER JOIN Artiest ON Song.artiestid = Artiest.artiestid
WHERE Lijst.top2000jaar LIKE @Year
```

I got this error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery >follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

change the subqueries to `SELECT TOP 1 ...` or `SELECT MAX(...) ...`